# Get parent nodes by child node selector with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to parse json with jq

```
{
    "xxx": {
        "aliases": {
            "business_event": {
                "is_write_index": true
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "business_event_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "clientName": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "componentName": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "correlationId": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "executionTime": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "fullDescription": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "shortDescription": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to construct an list of properties where type == "text", so that result would look like:

```
"fullDescription": {
    "type": "text"
},
"shortDescription": {
    "type": "text"
}
```

I've tried to use selectors, but the result is invalid

```
.xxx.mappings[].properties | select (.[].type=="text")
```

What is the correct way of quering child node and returning parent?

Comment: .xxx.mappings[].properties | to_entries[]  | select(.value.type=="text") | .key Worked for me (I needed keys anyway). Still looks too complicated

Answer (score 1):

The issue with

```
.xxx.mappings[].properties | select(.[].type=="text")
```

is that the `select` would select the whole `properties` object (not an array) as many times as there are sub-objects in it that has `.type == "text"`.

You may use `with_entries` here:

```bsh
jq '.xxx.mappings[].properties | with_entries(select(.value.type == "text"))' file
```

This iterates with `with_entries` over the properties. The `select` gets an array of elements like this:

```json
{
  "key": "clientName",
  "value": {
    "type": "keyword"
  }
}
```

The `select` picks out the elements with `.value.type == "text"` and these are then turned back to ordinary objects.

The output will be

```json
{
  "fullDescription": {
    "type": "text"
  },
  "shortDescription": {
    "type": "text"
  }
}
```

Note that a JSON documents can't contain "bare" keys (keys not part of an object), so the exact format of the output that you request is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

if you open to consider alternatives, then here's one based on walk-path unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'[type]:<text>:[-1]' -l
"fullDescription": {
   "type": "text"
}
"shortDescription": {
   "type": "text"
}
bash $
```

Walk-path (`-w`) is rather simple here:

- `[type]:<text>:` - will find recursively each (all) of `"type": "text"`, then from found entries
- `[-1]` - will back up 1 level (up the Json tree), effectively selecting its parent

`-l` instructs to print a label for the walked entry

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool